Some apps display a short description along with the screenshots
This morning, I noticed that while some apps on the Play Store show a "short description" alongside screenshots and videos, others only show the screenshots and videos without any description. I tried to figure out the possible way for this but no luck.
Is there an option to enable a short description on the store listing page for our app?


may it just a landscape image added by the developer?

I opened the same "Imagine" app to see the same but I did not see any text there only a screenshot can you? can you please elaborate more on how you see this and how you see the same as you put the image?

@Iftekhar This is not possible because these things are available in many apps.

@HanifShaikh Just search any app on the Play Store.  In the app listing click on the expand collapse options of the top 20 apps. Out of the top 20 apps, you will get this result. the first card with short descriptions.

Where is expend collapse option ?

Right arrow after app details(Name, ratings and download)

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

@HiteshSurani Yes, I got it. As per my research, I see it shows Google Play Team from a description

Sometimes when you write the exact name of the app in the search bar, Google Play will show the app in a larger space than usual. it shows differently for different people.
Google is testing different ways to show apps when write the exact name to increase conversion. sometimes they will show the short description under the video, sometimes under screenshots, and sometimes like the way you've share.
try to search for exact names of apps to see the different ways Google will test this.
Also you could press the arrow next to the app name to extend the app card and see how Google try these variations.
 
UPDATE: another note: I've notice that if the app didn't have the same localization as the phone, this will not appear at all, this include English-US, English-UK ...etc.


Thanks for the insight!. Regarding the first app in the list, I'm aware that, Playstore is showing the first app with a large preview scale.  "sometimes they will show the short description", I believe this is wrong because I tried this thing with many apps and only selected apps always showing short description with "From publisher tag".

@HiteshSurani I think, and this is speculation, Google is A/B testing with these, this is why some apps will appear to you like that but will not appear like that for other users. I can confirm that some of the apps I manage are showing this and some are not, even though the store listing structure are the same for most of these apps (btw I am talking about 60+ apps)

@HiteshSurani another note: I've notice that if the app didn't have the same localization as the phone, this will not appear at all, this include English-US, English-UK ...etc.

I really appreciate that you have reviewed the 60+ apps. This language thing is awesome, I will check that too. Thanks!

I worked on https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fit_with_pari app and it's showing the "from the publisher" though the primary language for this app is en-US and my device's preferred language is en-IN.

@HiteshSurani please check the screenshot added to the answer, I think I deserve best answer ;)

Thanks for your help, but I still need more clarification, as the screenshot doesn't provide any useful information.
